PowerShell equivalent of VBScript's MsgBox
Since the deprecation and removal of VBScript is soon to become a reality :( I feel the need to actually learn PowerShell properly.
What's the equivalent of VBScript's MsgBox function? In VBScript it was very functional, memorable, minimalist.. In PowerShell though, this is the nicest thing I can find:
using assembly System.Windows.Forms
using namespace System.Windows.Forms
[MessageBox]::Show("Hello")

Which is pretty messy by comparison to VBScript, and changing the script's namespace might not be appropriate.
Is there a way to just have command like $msgbox.show()? preferably so I don't have to fully qualify the Class name every time. Maybe with Add-Type or Alias?
I've looked around and not really found anything better than the above.

Unclear what you mean by "all the windows forms stuff rolled up into one command". Are you looking for a wrapper like Show-MessageBox.ps1 ?

I'll update the question with more clarity

You will have to Add-Type the assembly either WinForms or PresentationFramework and Show is a static member for MessageBox in both namespaces so the ::Show is needed for both. The easiest to simplify things is via a function that wraps the class functionalities (like the one from the link above) that you can add to your $profile script

Mathias' answer provides you with what you asked for, specifically (though you may want to add additional pass-through arguments, such as icon style, buttons, ...). For a PowerShell-idiomatic wrapper similar to the one Santiago linked to, see this answer (it also supports macOS).

My question is not a duplicate of "show a message box thats compatible with mac and windows"... obviously.

You can add the following statement to your profile script:
New-Variable -Name msgBox -Option AllScope,Constant -Value $( New-Object psobject |Add-Member -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name Show -Value {
  param([string]$Message)

  Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

  [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($Message)

} -PassThru )

Now you'll have a $msgBox variable available anywhere, referencing a dummy object with a Show() instance method attached, and you can thus do:
$msgBox.Show("Hello")


Nicely done, though I suggest adding additional pass-through parameters (what buttons to show, what icon, ...); with the help of parameter default values, this can still be mapped to a single [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show() call.

I'll accept this as the answer but a "profile script" is clunky.. What if someone runs my script who doesn't have this in their profile script? I'd have to include it in my script itself which sort of defeats the purpose.
